# Firebase logout user all sessions

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, firebase

I am using Firebase authentication in my iOS app. Is there any way in Firebase when user login my app with Firebase then logout that user all other devices(sessions)? Can I do that with Firebase admin SDK?

Comment: You need to it yourself for the mobile application. Take one token in User node in Firebase database and regenerate it every time you logged in into application, Match this token with already logged in user's token on `appDidBecomeActive` and `appDidFinishLaunching` method if token are different logged out the user manually and take user to authenticate screen.

Comment: Just a thought here but is that going to be a good user experience? I use my iOS devices so I can seamlessly move from one device to the other - chatting on my iMac and grab my phone on the go to continue the conversation (Handoff).

Comment: @Jay I think logout user for all sessions is good for security improvements.

Comment: @Jay It depends on the app category. If this is something related to security like banking, wallets, or personal data app then this is good to keep single user login.

Comment: @TheTiger I totally agree, which is why I asked. How users are handled is directly related to the use case of the app. I think a bit more info in the question could lead to an answer but as it, it's a bit vague as to what 'logout' means. In other words, Firebase could have an observer on a node that notifies the app to log the user out of Firebase but does that also mean to log the user out of the App itself? Or should they still have access to the data they are examining at the time with no new data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When i had this issue i resolved it with cloud functions
Please visit this link for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens

Do the following;

1. Set up web server with firebase cloud functions (if none exists)
2. use the admin sdk(thats the only way this method would work) - [Visit this link] (
   (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk).
3. Create an api that receives the uid and revokes current sessions as specified in the first link above

```
  admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
    .then(() => {
      return admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000;
    })
    .then((timestamp) => {
      //return valid response to ios app to continue the user's login process
  });
```

Voila users logged out. I hope this gives insight into resolving the issue

Comment: Wouldn't this "logout" current session as well?

Comment: Yes @JamesChen it would logout *all* active session

Comment: How can I preserve user logged in for current device and logout in all other devices?

Comment: This takes a lot of time to log out. Am I missing something here or is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

`Firebase` doesn't provide such feature. You need to manage it yourself.

Here is the [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) and they haven't mentioned anything related to single user sign in.

**Here is what you can do for this-**

Take one token in User node (Where you save user's other data) in `Firebase` database and regenerate it every time you logged in into application, Match this token with already logged in user's token (Which is saved locally) in `appDidBecomeActive` and `appDidFinishLaunching` or possibly each time you perform any operation with `Firebase` or may be in some fixed time interval. If tokens are different logged out the user manually and take user to authenticate screen.

Answer (score 2):

What i have done is:

Created collection in firestore called "activeSessions".User email as an id for object and "activeID" field for holding most recent session id.

in sign in page code:

Generating id for a user session every time user is logging in.
Add this id to localstorage(should be cleaned everytime before adding).
Replace "activeID" by generated id in collection "activeSessions" with current user email.

```
function addToActiveSession() {
  var sesID = gen();

  var db = firebase.firestore();
  localStorage.setItem('userID', sesID);
  db.collection("activeSessions").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email).set({
    activeID: sesID
  }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });

}
function gen() {
  var buf = new Uint8Array(1);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(buf);
  return buf[0];
}
function signin(){
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user) {
      
      localStorage.clear();
      addToActiveSession();
      }
    }), function (error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        alert('wrong pass');
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
    };
}
```

Then i am checking on each page if the id session in local storage is the same as "activeID" in firestore,if not then log out.

```
function checkSession(){
  
  var db = firebase.firestore();
  var docRef = db.collection("activeSessions").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email);
        docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
          alert(doc.data().activeID);
          alert(localStorage.getItem('userID'));
          if (doc.data().activeID != localStorage.getItem('userID')) {
            alert("bie bie");
            firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
        
              window.location.href = "signin.html";
         }).catch((error) => {
           // An error happened.
         });
            window.location.href = "accountone.html";
          } else{alert("vse ok");}
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
}
```

PS: window has to be refreshed to log inactive session out.