# Logout from all devices as user account deleted from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have web and mobile versions of the app. I am logged in with the same account on mobile and the web. When I deleted my account on mobile, I was able to perform all the actions on the web. So, how can I log out the user from all the devices when the user account is deleted?

Comment: You may call the function await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(); after the user is deleted.

Comment: @SowatKheang It will only log out from one device. But I want to log out from all the devices on which the user is logged in with the same account.

Comment: The document does not mention anything regarding single-user sign-in. We have to manage it by ourselves, you may check [firebase-logout-user-all-sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704253/firebase-logout-user-all-sessions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firebase` does not provide such feature but you can follow the trick as below.

```
 _checkIfAccountIsDeleted() async {
    try {
      IdTokenResult? idTokenResult =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdTokenResult(true);

      if (idTokenResult == null || idTokenResult.token == null) {
        print("User is deleted");
        //   FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
        // do logout stuff here...
      } else {
        print("User is available");
      }
    } catch (er) {
      print("User is deleted");
      //   FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    }
  }
```

I have checked it and it is working fine in my case.